# Sketching a set of Re$(iz) > \text{Im}(iz)$ on the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to sketch a set of $\text{Re}(iz) > \text{Im}(iz)$. I know that if I divide $b$etween a real and a imaginary part, I get:

- $\text{Re}(iz) = -b$
- $\text{Im}(iz) = a$

Then I know that I can visualize this region in the complex plane by drawing $- b > a$, which is similar to $-y>x$ on a 'normal', cartesian plane.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right

Comment: Yes you're right. $-b > a$ is same as plot of $y < -x$.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to make sure.